# QGIS Aggregate function missing

Tags: qgis, polygon, area

I want to sum the areas of several polygons in the same shape layer by using the *Aggregate* function in *Select features using an expression*. However, I can't find the Aggregate menu nor the SUM function within it. Where do I find it? I think I have installed most plug-ins connected to this function.

2.14.15 on a mac

Answer (score 3):

2.14 is too old for that functionality - it was introduced in 2.16.

Comment: The question was an interesting one, so it would be nice if you include in your answer how to do it in 2.16

Comment: This answer seems perfectly valid to me. It completely addresses the issue that the OP was having.